# Check first element

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have problem with check first element. If first element from string `lista` not be 'fe' string must be incorrect. Now my code skips all 'x' char but how I can check is the first word of string is 'fe'?

```
my_dict = {'dai':5,'ain':3,'jee':3,'je':2,'ne':2,'ai':2,'fe': 1,}
lista="xxxxxxxxxxfenejee"
for word in my_dict:
    if word=='fe':
        a=lista.find('fe')
        lista=lista[a:]
        print(lista)
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Could you be a bit more verbose? It's not exactly clear what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: your question says you want to print the string if it starts with 'fe' and your code written like you want to strip string to make it starts with 'fe' if it is not so what exactly you want and what's the purpose of dictionary here?

Comment: @Gahan Yes I try print the string if starts with 'fe' and strip the string before 'fe'. Dict is here becouse for every that words occurrence i must add value from 'my_dict'

Comment: @Graku specify this content and requirement in detail in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the string method `startswith()`

```
if word.startswith('fe'):
    print(word)
```

Comment: Thanks for help :)) It's exactly what I looking for:)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check if string starts with some another string there is a function for it

```
lista.startswith('fe')
```

Comment: Thanks !!! returned true :) I didn't know is that function :))